# How to remove 1 in every 2.8 elements of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, math, indexing

I have a an array which has a dynamic size, Which means that every time it'll be created it might have a different size.

And i have a constant int which is 17000

When the array gets initialized, i want to grab the amount of my constant variable and deduct it from the array in a sorted way from the beginning to the end.

Lets say if the array's size 34000, i'll grab 1 in every 2. and in the end it'll give me 17000 items from that array from the beginning to the end in a sorted way.

or if for example the array is 51000 i'll grab 1 in every 3. from the beginning to the end of the array.

now if the array size is for example 476000, then i have to grab 1 in every 2.8.

I don't know how to do that, and i don't even know how to ask my question so that google can help me.

I asked on the quroa from people who know math and they couldn't help me, which might be because of the way i explained my problem. but here i have more room to write and explain.

Needless to say that i don't want to do remove my constant variable from one side of the array like
removing 0-16999 or visa versa. i want this to happen in a sorted way because the elements of the dynamic array are related to each other, and in case i have to remove some them, i want to do keep at least one  from every part/every 2, 3 or 4 element depending on the size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: Always grab 1 element in every `array.size()/constant` gap

Comment: Do you want to "thin out" the original array and keep the order or can the elements in the resulting array be in any order?

Comment: if the array size is for example 476000, then you have to grab 1 in every 2 and thus creating your 17000 array and leaving some of the items. Since you can't change the constant then its clearly means that some items are expected to be left out.

Comment: @MOehm oh exactly the first one. i want to have the original order because the order is super important, but i want to thin it out.

Comment: Yeah in any case you need to keep the sorting in mind. In my opinion sorting should be done before the grabbing part i.e., first sort all 476000 then take out ur 17000 items

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan no i can't change the order, someone else has made that order and it is important, and all i have to remove is 17000 no more no less.

Comment: Dear @MOehm I noticed you removed your answer. I read your answer and it was useful. and, removing it also helped me because i had to do other testings to see which answer i should go with. Just wanted to say thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see it right what you want to do is increment index by `2.8` but truncated to integer. If your old array size is `n` and want to have new size `m`:

```
m = n - n/2.8
```

Now its just matter of linearly interpolating between `j=<0..n)` versus `i=<0..m)` and doing it in reverse will ease up the problems with changing unprocessed indexes after deletion.

```cpp
for (i=m-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
   j=(i*(n-1))/(m-1);
   // remove j-th element from array
   }
```

this should remove every 2.8 th element from your original array preserving the overall order/density ... This works on `n*m <= 2^9` on 32 bit integers.

**[edit1] modified DDA aproach to avoid integer overflow**

```cpp
int a[100],n=100,m=70;      // input array, olds size,new size
int i,j,c;                  // helper variables
for (c=n,i=0,j=0;i<n;i++)   // reorder array to new size O(n)
    {
    c-=m;
    if (c<=0){ c+=n; a[j]=a[i]; j++; }
    }
// here a[70] holds your new data
```

This should work without problems for `m+n <= 2*10^9` on 32 bit integers. This approach is the same as the previous one however the multiplication and division is divided to set of additions and substractions done in each iteration leading to subresult matching the `j` result ... where the intermediate subresult `c` is maxed at `m+n` instead of `m*n` like in the first approach.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. I'm trying it now

Comment: Dear Spektre it took some time for me to implement it. that's why writing this after 1 hour
Thank you for this answer, it helped me do what i wanted to do.

Comment: Dear Spektre, i ran into a problem with this approach.

When my constant variable is a high number, this `j` generates a negative number.

for example when the array came with 96000 items, and my constant is 17000, it works perfectly, and it gets 17000 items in a sorted way, but if my constant is 30000, it'll generate negative number and ruins everything.

do you know what's going on?

Comment: @AmirrezaMoeiniYegane Yes you are overflowing 32bit integer as `30000*96000 = 2880000000` which is bigger than `2^31` which is max positive integer 32bit int can hold. To remedy you can use unsigned integers that will give you limit `~4000000000` instead of current `~2000000000` or use 64bit variables if you have them. Another option is to not multiply and divide I added edit to my answer with DDA approach doing exactly that + fast `O(n)` data resize avoiding `O(n^2)` problems during delete on per item manner as a bonus...

Comment: Dear Spektre you're totally right, i was overflowing the integer, i changed that to uint beforing seeing your comment, and it worked. 
i might need to change it to double or long, or even ulong depending on how big the dynamic array might be.
btw, thank you for editing your answer, i really appreciate that.

Comment: Actually, i modified you first approach and im doing it from 0 upward instead of doing this backward as you suggested, it's working fine for me, but just wanted to know, do you think there might be a problem that i'm not aware of?

Comment: if you are iterating forward and copying the data like I did in my second approach you fine, however if you delete/remove instead (like in the first approach) then the indexes that got to be deleted next are shifted by one. For example you want to delete every 3th index so 0,3,6,9,... but when you delete `0` the index `3` become index `2`  and you are deleting wrong element (which does not happen if you go backwards) the longer array the more statistical differences you got on the end of array. Unless you account for the deleted elements by decrementing indexes to delete on each removal ...

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, I know arrays are always indexed by integers thus you can actually loop using floats.

1. You can either round the result to the upper or the lower bound and pick the numbers, creating an array that it is actually close to the size you want.

```js
const gap = Math.round(476000/170000); // 3
const items = Array(476000).fill('').map(() => Math.random())
const arr = [];
for(let i =0; i< 476000; i = i + gap) {
    arr.push(items[i]);
}
```

2. You can calculate how many items you want upfront assuming that you will have lots of numbers in places. Since the results are sorted you can always sort the array before applying any changes:

```js
const foo = items.sort((a, b) => a > b);
const final = foo.splice(0, 17000 * 2.8)
```

Comment: due to FPU rounding errors adding gap this way will lead to cumulative errors to the end of array corrupting statistical, density and ordering properties of the array OP wants to preserve. You can do the same without cumulative errors by linear interpolation done in the same way as my 1st approach where `c=(n-1))/(m-1)` is a floating constant so just single multiply + truncation to int on each iteration so simply `j = floor(i*c)`

Comment: Yeap, it makes sense. Using 2.8 as a step and rounding the index of the array. Nice one, although the original question is a bit absurd.

Comment: "absurd" not really its a form of down-sampling ... You can look at it as nearest neighbor.